# Matching string without specific pattern between specific places

Tags: php, regex

```
$example_string = "<a class="190"><br>hello.. 8/10<br><a class="154"><br>9/10<br>"
```

what i need to match is the classes and the "rating" part (8/10).

Something like this, except i dont know how to write `(ANYTHING EXCEPT <br> here)` in regexp:

```
preg_match_all('#class="([0-9]{3})"><br>(ANYTHING EXCEPT <br> here)*?([0-9]/10)#', 
$example_string, matches);
```

So a preg_match_all should give these results:

```
$matches[1][1] = '190';
$matches[1][2] = '8/10';
$matches[2][1] = '154';
$matches[2][2] = '9/10';
```

Answer (score 1):

to work off of your pattern, and to answer your question

```
class="([0-9]{3})"><br>(?:(?!<br>).)*?([0-9]\/10)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/151)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know php, but it should work as it does in python...

get the matches between "classes", and iterate to get your data in the returned matched strings

```
import re # the regex module
example_string = '"<a class="190"><br>hello.. 8/10<br><a class="154"><br>9/10<br>"'

for match in re.findall(r'(?:class[^\d]")([^\/]+)(?!class)', example_string):
    print(list(re.findall(r'(\d+)', match)))
```

yields the following lists:

```
['190', '8']
['154', '9']
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants.

Comment: @vks How can OP *not* want Python? ;-)

Comment: @Ja͢ck the output i am talking about

Answer (score 0):

A simple DOM parser would be able to give you that information:

```
$example_string = '<a class="190"><br>hello.. 8/10<br><a class="154"><br>9/10<br>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($example_string);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// get all text nodes that have an anchor parent with a class attribute
$query = '//text()[parent::a[@class]]';

foreach ($xpath->query($query) as $node) {
    echo $node->textContent, "\n";
    echo "parent node: ", $node->parentNode->getAttribute('class'), "\n";
}
```

#### Output

```
hello.. 8/10
parent node: 190
9/10
parent node: 154
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=class=")(\d+)|(\d+\/\d+)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/58

```
$re = "/(?<=class=\")(\\d+)|(\\d+\\/\\d+)/";
$str = "<a class=\"190\"><br>hello.. 8/10<br><a class=\"154\"><br>9/10<br>";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```